# Can I use the default image editor available in my iOS app?

Tags: ios

I want to implement an image editing functionality similar to the native one provided by Apple in iPhones. Is it available to use inside the app? If not then is there any similar library available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You can't just pull up the built-in editing controls, though. You'll need to apply filters and effects using CoreImage. 
[This tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76285/beginning-core-image-swift) has a step by step process on how to apply filters like sepia and black and white.

Comment: What's the Class for in built editing controls called?

Comment: It's called Core Image.

Comment: read about it more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html

Comment: apologies, misread your answer. I thought you said you could pull up the built-in controls... but you said you can't (quite rightly).

Comment: This answer is misleading. The answer should be "no, there is no way to use the standard image editing found in the Photos app within a 3rd party app".

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across this question nowadays, please look into adding a `photo editing extension` to your app and using the `PHContentEditingController` protocol to launch the native photo editor.

Here's [a great walkthrough](https://www.answertopia.com/ios/creating-an-ios-photo-editing-extension/) for iOS 16.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to apply to the question. As I read the OP, the user wants to have standard image editing for use within their own app. This answer provides a pointer for developing your own custom image editing that is meant to be used within the Photos app. Not at all the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, I mis-read that. Will hide this answer.